# Accessing in6_addr members on windows

Tags: c, windows

I have an app that sends and receives udp datagrams and works only with IPv4 addresses. It is integrated into a build system such that the same source is used to build binaries for both windows and linux. I'm trying to enhance it to work with IPv6.

My updated source builds and works fine for linux but I'm having trouble accessing members of the in6_addr struct on windows. Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, I defined the following macro:

```
#define IPV4_ADDR_ARGS(in6p) \
  (in6p).u.Byte[12],(in6p).s6_addr.u.Byte[13], \
  (in6p).s6_addr.u.Byte[14],(in6p).s6_addr.u.Byte[15]
```

and tried to print the last 4 bytes of the mapped IPv4 address as:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 *in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) ipAddr; // ipAddr is of type sockaddr_storage*

if (IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED(&in6->sin6_addr)) {
    printf("ip:%u.%u.%u.%u", IPV4_ADDR_ARGS(in6->sin6_addr));
}
```

However, the compiler throws an error like this:

server.c: error C2224: left of '.u' must have struct/union type

Is there another way to access the bytes of an IPv6 address from struct in6_addr? 
I don't have control over the build system and the only output I see from it is the result of the compilation (and a path to the binaries if the build succeeds).

Comment: (Please don't use HTML `<code>` tags, use Markdown. There's plenty of help available in the editor.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is simply the ampersand (`&`) in the call to your macro.  Your macro references an instance of in6_addr, not a pointer to one.

**Update.**  You also have a typo in your macro.  It should be defined as follows (without the s6_addr member)

```
#define IPV4_ADDR_ARGS(in6p) (in6p).u.Byte[12], (in6p).u.Byte[13], (in6p).u.Byte[14], (in6p).u.Byte[15]
```

Then instead of this:

```
if (IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED(&in6->sin6_addr)) {
    printf("ip:%u.%u.%u.%u", IPV4_ADDR_ARGS(in6->sin6_addr));
}
```

This instead:

```
if (IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED(in6->sin6_addr)) {
    printf("ip:%u.%u.%u.%u", IPV4_ADDR_ARGS(in6->sin6_addr));
}
```